# itesseract-ocrを利用したiOSアプリの開発におけるOCR（光学文字認識）で発生するエラーについて。

Tags: objective-c, xcode

現在iOSでOCR（光学文字認識）をするために、tesseract-ocrを利用しています。
http://blog.isana.net/2014/08/ios.html　などを参照してXcodeでテストしてみたのですが下記のようなエラーが出て、検索しても解決策を見つけられないためこちらで質問させていただきました。

```
/Users/user/Documents/iOSProjects/iOSApp/tessdata/eng.cube.lm:7: premature EOF
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lex failed with exit code 1
```

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list　でtesseract-ocr-3.02.eng.tar.gzをダウンロードし、プロジェクト内にコピーしました。

プログラムは

```
- (NSString *)scanImage:(UIImage *)image {

Tesseract *tesseract = [[Tesseract alloc] initWithLanguage:@"eng"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" forKey:@"tessedit_char_whitelist"];
[tesseract setVariableValue:@".,:;'" forKey:@"tessedit_char_blacklist"];

if (image) {
    [tesseract setImage:image];
    [tesseract recognize];
    return [tesseract recognizedText];
}
return nil;}
```

のようになっております。

対処法などご教授いただけますと非常に助かります。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcodeが`eng.cube.lm`をLexのソースコードと勘違いしてコンパイルしてしまい、エラーが発生している可能性があります。  
`eng.cube.lm`のTypeを`Data`などに変更してコンパイルを回避してみてください。

[image: Xcode]

Comment: おっしゃる通りの原因でした。Typeを修正したところ上手く作動いたしました。
ありがとうございました！